# Ansible - Find File with a Specific Path and Copy it to a Specific Pre-Set Destination from a Dictionary

Tags: ansible

I've got a problem that I've been trying to solve for a few days and I'm starting to think I'm just not going to get it.  So, here I am.

I have to write an Ansible playbook that will look for a a bunch of files in a bunch of repos and, if it should happen to find that file in those repos, copy it to a specific destination directory which will be pre-set and specific to that file.  A catch is that there might be multiple instances of that file but we only want that file if it's under a specific sub-directory in the path (the location of the sub-directory changes from repo to repo and the directory structure of the repos are all pretty different).

So that I don't put you all through our terrible naming conventions, I've abstracted the problem to this kinda silly example.

Let's say that this is our directory structure:

```
/tmp/example
└── foods
    ├── breakfast
    │   ├── pancakes
    │   └── waffles
    ├── dinner
    │   ├── fish
    │   └── pasta
    └── lunch
        ├── burger
        └── burrito
```

And this is our dictionary that states the user, the food they want, and the destination path of the food should we find it:

```
orders:
  'Bob':
    food: 'burrito'
    dst: '/tmp/example-homes/home/bob/plate'
  'Jack':
    food: 'fish'
    dst: '/tmp/example-homes/home/jack/plate'
  'Mary':
    food: 'fish'
    dst: '/tmp/example-homes/mary/plate'
```

Now, let's say that we want to iterate through the list of people in the orders dictionary and find their food item in /tmp/example, **BUT** it should only match if their food choice is under the foods/lunch directory.  If we happen to find their food in the foods/lunch directory, copy it to that user's specified dst directory (notice that not all of the dst directories are the same).  Skip the food if it's found under foods/breakfast or foods/dinner or even something like restaurant/lunch; we only care about foods/lunch.  For example, Mary wants fish, and fish does exist, but it's in the foods/dinner directory so we're going to consider it as missing and not copy it.

I've gotten to the point where I can find the food but I'm stuck trying to tie that found food file to the dst field that tells us where the food should go.  It's frustrating because I feel that all of the data that I need is actually in the find_food_results dictionary.  I just don't know how to act on the results of find so as to perform the logical equivalent of "if food matched, and path contains 'foods/lunch', copy it to item.value.dst".

I also can't help but feel that there's a simpler way to do this and I'm just chasing my tail at this point.  Anyhow, thanks a bunch in advance.  Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Here's the code:

```
---

- name: "directory finder"
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local

  vars:

    orders:
      'Bob':
        food: 'burrito'
        dst: '/tmp/example-homes/home/bob/plate'
      'Jack':
        food: 'fish'
        dst: '/tmp/example-homes/home/jack/plate'
      'Mary':
        food: 'fish'
        dst: '/tmp/example-homes/mary/plate'


  tasks:

    - name: "describe orders"
      debug:
        var: orders

    - name: "describe orders | dict2items"
      debug:
        var: orders | dict2items

    - name: "find the food"
      find:
        paths: "/tmp/example"
        recurse: yes
        file_type: file
        patterns:  "{{ item.value.food }}"
      with_items:
         - "{{ orders | dict2items }}"
      register: find_food_results

    - name: "describe find_food_results"
      debug:
        var: find_food_results

    - name: "narrow down our findings to paths that contain 'foods/lunch'"
      set_fact:
        food_lunch_directory_paths: "{{ food_lunch_directory_paths | default([]) }} + [ '{{ item.path }}' ]"
      with_items: "{{ find_food_results.results | map(attribute='files') | list }}"
      when: "'foods/lunch' in item.path"

    - name: "describe our food/lunch paths"
      debug:
        var: food_lunch_directory_paths
```

And here's the output:

```
PLAY [directory finder] *******************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [describe orders] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "orders": {
        "Bob": {
            "dst": "/tmp/example-homes/home/bob/plate",
            "food": "burrito"
        },
        "Jack": {
            "dst": "/tmp/example-homes/home/jack/plate",
            "food": "fish"
        },
        "Mary": {
            "dst": "/tmp/example-homes/mary/plate",
            "food": "fish"
        }
    }
}

TASK [describe orders | dict2items] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "orders | dict2items": [
        {
            "key": "Bob",
            "value": {
                "dst": "/tmp/example-homes/home/bob/plate",
                "food": "burrito"
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "Jack",
            "value": {
                "dst": "/tmp/example-homes/home/jack/plate",
                "food": "fish"
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "Mary",
            "value": {
                "dst": "/tmp/example-homes/mary/plate",
                "food": "fish"
            }
        }
    ]
}

TASK [find the food] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'key': u'Bob', u'value': {u'food': u'burrito', u'dst': u'/tmp/example-homes/home/bob/plate'}})
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'key': u'Jack', u'value': {u'food': u'fish', u'dst': u'/tmp/example-homes/home/jack/plate'}})
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'key': u'Mary', u'value': {u'food': u'fish', u'dst': u'/tmp/example-homes/mary/plate'}})


TASK [describe find_food_results] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "find_food_results": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "examined": 10,
                "failed": false,
                "files": [
                    {
                        "atime": 1604184466.0584693,
                        "ctime": 1604184466.0584693,
                        "dev": 66305,
                        "gid": 0,
                        "gr_name": "root",
                        "inode": 58724223,
                        "isblk": false,
                        "ischr": false,
                        "isdir": false,
                        "isfifo": false,
                        "isgid": false,
                        "islnk": false,
                        "isreg": true,
                        "issock": false,
                        "isuid": false,
                        "mode": "0644",
                        "mtime": 1604184466.0584693,
                        "nlink": 1,
                        "path": "/tmp/example/foods/lunch/burrito",
                        "pw_name": "root",
                        "rgrp": true,
                        "roth": true,
                        "rusr": true,
                        "size": 0,
                        "uid": 0,
                        "wgrp": false,
                        "woth": false,
                        "wusr": true,
                        "xgrp": false,
                        "xoth": false,
                        "xusr": false
                    }
                ],
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "age": null,
                        "age_stamp": "mtime",
                        "contains": null,
                        "depth": null,
                        "excludes": null,
                        "file_type": "file",
                        "follow": false,
                        "get_checksum": false,
                        "hidden": false,
                        "paths": [
                            "/tmp/example"
                        ],
                        "patterns": [
                            "burrito"
                        ],
                        "recurse": true,
                        "size": null,
                        "use_regex": false
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "key": "Bob",
                    "value": {
                        "dst": "/tmp/example-homes/home/bob/plate",
                        "food": "burrito"
                    }
                },
                "matched": 1,
                "msg": ""
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "examined": 10,
                "failed": false,
                "files": [
                    {
                        "atime": 1604184480.3713806,
                        "ctime": 1604184480.3713806,
                        "dev": 66305,
                        "gid": 0,
                        "gr_name": "root",
                        "inode": 62917805,
                        "isblk": false,
                        "ischr": false,
                        "isdir": false,
                        "isfifo": false,
                        "isgid": false,
                        "islnk": false,
                        "isreg": true,
                        "issock": false,
                        "isuid": false,
                        "mode": "0644",
                        "mtime": 1604184480.3713806,
                        "nlink": 1,
                        "path": "/tmp/example/foods/dinner/fish",
                        "pw_name": "root",
                        "rgrp": true,
                        "roth": true,
                        "rusr": true,
                        "size": 0,
                        "uid": 0,
                        "wgrp": false,
                        "woth": false,
                        "wusr": true,
                        "xgrp": false,
                        "xoth": false,
                        "xusr": false
                    }
                ],
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "age": null,
                        "age_stamp": "mtime",
                        "contains": null,
                        "depth": null,
                        "excludes": null,
                        "file_type": "file",
                        "follow": false,
                        "get_checksum": false,
                        "hidden": false,
                        "paths": [
                            "/tmp/example"
                        ],
                        "patterns": [
                            "fish"
                        ],
                        "recurse": true,
                        "size": null,
                        "use_regex": false
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "key": "Jack",
                    "value": {
                        "dst": "/tmp/example-homes/home/jack/plate",
                        "food": "fish"
                    }
                },
                "matched": 1,
                "msg": ""
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "examined": 10,
                "failed": false,
                "files": [
                    {
                        "atime": 1604184480.3713806,
                        "ctime": 1604184480.3713806,
                        "dev": 66305,
                        "gid": 0,
                        "gr_name": "root",
                        "inode": 62917805,
                        "isblk": false,
                        "ischr": false,
                        "isdir": false,
                        "isfifo": false,
                        "isgid": false,
                        "islnk": false,
                        "isreg": true,
                        "issock": false,
                        "isuid": false,
                        "mode": "0644",
                        "mtime": 1604184480.3713806,
                        "nlink": 1,
                        "path": "/tmp/example/foods/dinner/fish",
                        "pw_name": "root",
                        "rgrp": true,
                        "roth": true,
                        "rusr": true,
                        "size": 0,
                        "uid": 0,
                        "wgrp": false,
                        "woth": false,
                        "wusr": true,
                        "xgrp": false,
                        "xoth": false,
                        "xusr": false
                    }
                ],
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "age": null,
                        "age_stamp": "mtime",
                        "contains": null,
                        "depth": null,
                        "excludes": null,
                        "file_type": "file",
                        "follow": false,
                        "get_checksum": false,
                        "hidden": false,
                        "paths": [
                            "/tmp/example"
                        ],
                        "patterns": [
                            "fish"
                        ],
                        "recurse": true,
                        "size": null,
                        "use_regex": false
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "key": "Mary",
                    "value": {
                        "dst": "/tmp/example-homes/mary/plate",
                        "food": "fish"
                    }
                },
                "matched": 1,
                "msg": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}

TASK [narrow down our findings to paths that contain 'foods/lunch'] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'rusr': True, u'uid': 0, u'rgrp': True, u'xoth': False, u'islnk': False, u'woth': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'mtime': 1604184466.0584693, u'gr_name': u'root', u'path': u'/tmp/example/foods/lunch/burrito', u'xusr': False, u'atime': 1604184466.0584693, u'inode': 58724223, u'isgid': False, u'size': 0, u'isdir': False, u'wgrp': False, u'ctime': 1604184466.0584693, u'isblk': False, u'xgrp': False, u'isuid': False, u'dev': 66305, u'roth': True, u'isreg': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0644', u'pw_name': u'root', u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True})
skipping: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'rusr': True, u'uid': 0, u'rgrp': True, u'xoth': False, u'islnk': False, u'woth': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'mtime': 1604184480.3713806, u'gr_name': u'root', u'path': u'/tmp/example/foods/dinner/fish', u'xusr': False, u'atime': 1604184480.3713806, u'inode': 62917805, u'isgid': False, u'size': 0, u'isdir': False, u'wgrp': False, u'ctime': 1604184480.3713806, u'isblk': False, u'xgrp': False, u'isuid': False, u'dev': 66305, u'roth': True, u'isreg': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0644', u'pw_name': u'root', u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True})
skipping: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'rusr': True, u'uid': 0, u'rgrp': True, u'xoth': False, u'islnk': False, u'woth': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'mtime': 1604184480.3713806, u'gr_name': u'root', u'path': u'/tmp/example/foods/dinner/fish', u'xusr': False, u'atime': 1604184480.3713806, u'inode': 62917805, u'isgid': False, u'size': 0, u'isdir': False, u'wgrp': False, u'ctime': 1604184480.3713806, u'isblk': False, u'xgrp': False, u'isuid': False, u'dev': 66305, u'roth': True, u'isreg': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0644', u'pw_name': u'root', u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True})

TASK [describe our food/lunch paths] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "food_lunch_directory_paths": [
        "/tmp/example/foods/lunch/burrito"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take into account missing files. For example, given the orders

```yaml
    orders:
      'Bob':
        food: 'burrito'
        dst: '/tmp/example-homes/home/bob/plate'
      'Jack':
        food: 'fish'
        dst: '/tmp/example-homes/home/jack/plate'
      'Mary':
        food: 'fish'
        dst: '/tmp/example-homes/mary/plate'
      'Joe':
        food: 'steak'
        dst: '/tmp/example-homes/joe/plate'
```

Create the list of the foods

```yaml
    - name: "create list of foods"
      set_fact:
        foods: "{{ orders|dict2items|
                   map(attribute='value.food')|unique|sort|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: foods
```

gives

```yaml
  foods:
  - burrito
  - fish
  - steak
```

Find the files and create a dictionary of foods and related files. Then use the dictionary to copy the existing files to destinations

```yaml
    - name: "find the foods"
      find:
        paths: "/tmp/example"
        recurse: yes
        file_type: file
        patterns: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ foods }}"
      register: find_food_results

    - name: "create dictionary of foods"
      set_fact:
        foods: "{{ dict(foods|zip(paths)) }}"
      vars:
        paths: "{{ find_food_results.results|
                   map(attribute='files')|list }}"

    - name: "copy property files to destination"
      debug:
        msg: "Copy {{ foods[item.value.food][0]['path'] }} to {{ item.value.dst }}"
      with_dict: "{{ orders }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
      when: foods[item.value.food]|length > 0
```

give

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=Bob) => 
  msg: Copy /tmp/example/foods/lunch/burrito to /tmp/example-homes/home/bob/plate
ok: [localhost] => (item=Jack) => 
  msg: Copy /tmp/example/foods/dinner/fish to /tmp/example-homes/home/jack/plate
ok: [localhost] => (item=Mary) => 
  msg: Copy /tmp/example/foods/dinner/fish to /tmp/example-homes/mary/plate
skipping: [localhost] => (item=Joe)
```

---

Q: **"*File 'burrito' in the breakfast, lunch, and dinner directories ... How can I iterate over ... find_food_results.files? Almost like a nested loop.*"**

A: Display the dictionary *foods* with selected paths only. The task

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n')[:-1] }}"
      vars:
        msg: |
          {{ item.key }}
          {{ item.value|map(attribute='path')|list|to_nice_yaml }}
      loop: "{{ foods|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => (item=burrito) => 
  msg:
  - burrito
  - '- /tmp/example/foods/breakfast/burrito'
  - '- /tmp/example/foods/dinner/burrito'
  - '- /tmp/example/foods/lunch/burrito'
ok: [localhost] => (item=fish) => 
  msg:
  - fish
  - '- /tmp/example/foods/dinner/fish'
ok: [localhost] => (item=steak) => 
  msg:
  - steak
  - '[]'
```

Use *subelements* if you want to iterate the lists of the files. For example

```yaml
    - name: "List all property files"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1.path }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ foods|dict2items }}"
        - value
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [List all property files] ****
ok: [localhost] => (item=burrito) => 
  msg: burrito /tmp/example/foods/breakfast/burrito
ok: [localhost] => (item=burrito) => 
  msg: burrito /tmp/example/foods/dinner/burrito
ok: [localhost] => (item=burrito) => 
  msg: burrito /tmp/example/foods/lunch/burrito
ok: [localhost] => (item=fish) => 
  msg: fish /tmp/example/foods/dinner/fish
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing your solution!

Much of my anxiety with Ansible comes from not knowing how to manipulate layered data structures like dictionaries of dictionaries of lists, so I get a lot from seeing how different people solve problems that involve those types of data structures.

I like how you created the foods list and this is the first time I've seen the zip filter.  It seems similar to the combine filter.  What's the difference there?

Comment: [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) merges hashes.  You're welcome!

Comment: I found something that breaks my solution, but I'm not sure if it breaks yours.  I wonder if you could help.  If I have the file 'burrito' in the breakfast, lunch, and dinner directories, we can no longer access the results using the [0] because [0].path contains the "breakfast" burrito only (item.files[0].path contains the path for breakfast/burrito, item.files[1].path contains the path for the dinner/burrito, and item.files[2].path contains the path for the lunch/burrito.  How can I iterate over the find_food_results and over find_food_results.files?  Almost like a nested loop.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Open a new question if you have other issues. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ha!  I was just about to post that I figured out how to do it with "with_subelements" when I saw your answer.  It's a good sign that we both came up with the same solution :D  Thanks again so much!

Answer (score 0):

And of course as soon as I ask the question, I find the answer to it :-/

Well, in case anyone else was struggling with this, here's how I fixed it.  Though, I'd love to see more efficient solutions, so please do chime in if you have one.

I was able to create a new value in the dictionary called "src" that contained the path of the file found using the find module.  Then, in the copy module, I was able to iterate over the dictionary and only copy when the src contained 'foods/lunch'.

Here's the code:

```
---

- name: "directory finder"
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local

  vars:

    orders:
      'Bob':
        food: 'burrito'
        dst: '/tmp/example-homes/home/bob/plate'
      'Jack':
        food: 'fish'
        dst: '/tmp/example-homes/home/jack/plate'
      'Mary':
        food: 'fish'
        dst: '/tmp/example-homes/mary/plate'


  tasks:

    - name: "describe orders"
      debug:
        var: orders

    - name: "describe orders | dict2items"
      debug:
        var: orders | dict2items

    - name: "find the food"
      find:
        paths: "/tmp/example"
        recurse: yes
        file_type: file
        patterns:  "{{ item.value.food }}"
      with_items:
         - "{{ orders | dict2items }}"
      register: find_food_results

    - name: "create a src key/value dictionary element"
      set_fact:
        orders: "{{ orders | combine( new_item, recursive=true ) }}"
      vars:
        new_item: "{ '{{ item.item.key }}': { 'src': '{{ item.files[0].path }}' } }"
      with_items: "{{ find_food_results.results }}"

    - name: "copy property files to destination"
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.value.src }}"
        dest: "{{ item.value.dst }}"
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0644
      with_dict: "{{ orders }}"
      when: "'foods/lunch' in item.value.src"
```